# nvInitDll redirect success malforming PATH

Tags: windows-7, redirect, path, nvidia

I've run into a very strange issue and it seems like there's nobody else having the same problem (according to Google).

When I start "cmd" from Win+R and echo %PATH% it's ok. But when I start cmd from another program like FreeCommander or Ant and echo %PATH% I get

```
nvInitDll: App c:\dev\java1.6.0_22\bin\java.exe - redirect success.
```

(java.exe replaced by the program which is echoing PATH). And of course PATH doesn't then work.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. And it worked for some time but I can't trace back when it stopped working. I tried reinstalling nVidia drivers for my GeForce 310M but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem (the app is python in my case). Driver version is 257.38.  My thinkpad driver update isn't actually changing the driver version, which is infuriating.

Comment: By the way, if anyone is thinking of saying "This isn't a software developement problem", I'd say "keep it anyway" because the symptom as described (malformed PATH variables in child processes) will (almost always) only be visible to a developer. Ordinary users will just get "It doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I solved this by cleaning the nvidia drivers and then installing the newest one for Optimus (260.99). The problem then went away.